# <HTML> Previous Date Vallidation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

I'm looking to add a validation to the date on HTML.

Basically, when I select any previous date (before today) it should show a pop-up message telling me "You must select a valid date".

I don't want to blank out the dates. They must be able to select the wrong date and show a pop-up message.

Need to do it in HTML and JavaScript or JQuery.

```
<input id="txtDate" type="date">
```

Comment: are you using any date select plugins ?

Comment: whats your logic in checking the date ..clicking a validate button ?

Comment: @coolguy If for example, you chose 01/11/2015, it should show a pop-up box telling the user "Please select a valid date".

Comment: Thats what im asking how will you choose a date ? type in there and when do you want the validation ?

Comment: are you typing in the text box and comparing the type date?is there a format of what date format they are allowed to type if it is by typing?

Comment: @coolguy the date will be selected using a drop down calender. A messagebox should show straight away if the user was to select the previous dates.

Comment: what is the name of that plugin ..it surely has an inbuilt validator

Comment: @pekkka Not typing into the text box, it will be a dropdown calender. Calender format is dd/mm/yyy

Comment: @coolguy using Chrome to test me date box. I'm not using any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

if you would use the folloowing input field:

```
  <input type="date" id="datepicker" name="event_date" class="datepicker">
```

You could do something like this:

```
var selectedDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
var now = new Date();
if (selectedDate < now) {
  alert("Please select a valid date");
}
```

Its checks if the selected date is smaller then the current date. If that is the case you could do some action

Comment: @CollinKoornstra since the `datepicker()` function will only work on jQuery datapicker objects and not on plain type=date inputs, you may have to write a more complete example. Or just replace the first line of JS with `var selectedDate = document.querySelector('#datepicker').valueAsDate;`